# SparkViewEngine: Is there a functionality available that's equivalent to a PHP Include?

Tags: partial-views, spark-view-engine

I am using the SparkViewEngine with ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and was wondering if there is a way to include another View within your current view.

For example, I have this view called ResourceManager.spark.
Inside this file, I want to include another sub-view called Resources.spark.

Thanks!
Abe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using a partial file. The syntax is

```
<use file="Resources" />
```

it will then look for a file called Resources.spark in the View/`<ControllerName`> directory and if that isn't found in the shared directory.

If you name the file _Resources.spark then you could also use it as a custom element (sans the  underscore) like so

```
<resources />
```

for more information see http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/organizingcontent#Parsingandrenderingpartialfiles

Comment: It looks like DimeCasts.Net also posted a new tutorial on Partials (http://dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/157).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use named content areas.

Take a look at the documentation on the [Spark website](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/organizingcontent#Namedcontentsections)

There is also a good video tutorial at [DimeCasts.Net](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/156)

Comment: Hi Adam, I am actually looking to implement something more along the lines of a partial view. 

I do use content areas heavily on the project that I am working on and they work similar to the way master pages in ASP.NET works.

However, thank you for your suggestions and I definitely appreciate the link to DimeCasts.net; there's a lot of great screencasts.